# In yii2, how do I autoload my own PHP classes?

Tags: php, yii2

Inside my Controller I want a function to use `mpdf` e.g.

```
public function actionPdf(){

    include("MPDF57/mpdf.php");
    $mpdf=new mPDF('c'); 
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
    $mpdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'F');

    }

}
```

This does not work, and throws an error:

> Class 'app\controllers\mPDF' not found

What should I do If I want to autoload the class

(a). Just for this Controller Action

(b). To make it usable everywhere just by using the `use` statement.

I know it has to do something with `namespaces` but don't know how do I define a namespace, and where do I place this `MPDF57` folder and then make it accessible.

I also tried this :

```
 $name = "MPDF57/mpdf.php";
spl_autoload_register(function ($name) {
    var_dump($name);
});
```

But this didn't work either. throws the same error when I call my controller Action.

Here is the namespace declaration and `use` statements inside :

```
namespace app\controllers;

    use Yii;
    use app\models\Regs;
    use app\models\Voters;
    use app\models\RegsSearch;
    use yii\web\Controller;
    use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
    use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
    use \yii\web\Response;
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use kartik\mpdf\Pdf;
```

Comment: Can you show us the top of your file, with the use statements and eventually the namespace declaration ?

Comment: What is the path of mpdf.php relative to your Yii webroot?

Comment: namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Regs;
use app\models\Voters;
use app\models\RegsSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use \yii\web\Response;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\mpdf\Pdf;

Comment: Since you are using kartik mpdf extension, you don't need to install mpdf by yourself... And you should learn basics of php namespaces before asking this kind of question : http://php.net/manual/language.namespaces.php

Answer (score 0):

Yii has already had autoloader, you do need nothing to load your class.
Just create your class with correct namespace and it will be loaded where are you using it only.

Namspace should represent real path to PHP file. PHP file name and class name should be same.

Answer (score -1):

You should simply use [mpdf/mpdf](https://packagist.org/packages/mpdf/mpdf) package :

1. Install it using composer :

   `composer require "mpdf/mpdf" ">=6.0.0"`
2. Use it like this :

   `$mpdf = new \mPDF();`

Or you can use a yii2 extension like this one : https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf

Comment: i want  a solution to load my own classes. mpdf is just an example

Comment: My Question is "In yii2, how do I autoload my own PHP classes?". Now edit your answer if you can answer my question, I'll remove the downvote,  upvote and accept it!

Comment: Don't mix 2 differents questions in one. I won't  answer your questions anymore, or may be after your learn basics of php programming...

Comment: I'm still new and I'm still learning, and StackOverflow has been a great resource for me, and so you are, but tell me how my question is Invalid, I've done proper research, I read the documentation, but am unable to understand, that's why spend hours on this question, writing commenting and so on.  and that's the only why I'm requesting again to  answer. I know how to define a namespace. but don't know how do I include all the files under that namespace. Now don't expect me to dig through a 10 page long documentation just for this. That way I'll never become a programmer

Answer (score -1):

I've faced such problems in one of my previous projects. I'm not good at PHP or Yii2 - so follow my guide on your own risk :)

When you you add `use path\to\ExternalLibrary` that means the interface is ready to use inside current class (e.g. CurrentController.php).

That means your application knows how to bring your path to it's stage.

E.g. `use common\models\Post` lets you directly to use `Post` class, as `$posts = new Post;`

So if your library contains only one file, just put is some "canonic" path. To `common\models\` for example. So you can use it like any other model interface.

But for sake of your project put it on vendor folder. Then install a random library with composer. And observe which files are modified (1-3 generally). Also try to understand the modification logic. When you get sure that you've grasped everything, copy and paste these parts and change the paths, names, etc. for your library.

The best way, I think, is to make your library PSR-4 compatible and ship it as a PHP package. Thus, others can also benefit from your work.

There are lots of guides about making php packages.

- http://sitepoint.com/starting-new-php-package-right-way/
- https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/create-composer-package
- http://jessesnet.com/development-notes/2015/create-php-composer-package/
- http://culttt.com/2014/03/12/build-php-package/

If you are planning to be a good PHP developer,  I recommend to look up Josh Lockhart's "Modern PHP: New Features and Good Practices" book ( free pdfs are available :) ). That will help you to understand the fundamentals of OO PHP including namespaces, interfaces etc. So, you will be able to handle such problems in modern way.